# How to display shopify secure logo on product pages?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am running my e-Commerce website on Shopify. I would like to add a Shopify Secured image next in order to increase customer's trust on the page.

Similar to this [karambit fade](https://hobanco.com/products/cs-go-karambit-fade-doppler-irl) product page design

The Shopify Secured appears right below the "add to cart" button, next to the visa mastercard etc. symbols.

I want to know if there's a built in feature to toggle this, or maybe you need to edit the liquid template?

Or is there any Shopify app available for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to edit the `product-template.liquid` file (assuming you have a newer theme) and add this in where you want the badge to appear:

```
<img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/images/badges/shopify-secure-badge-light-shadow.png" alt="Shopify secure badge" />
```

Shopify has a tutorial you can follow here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/store/add-security-badge